# How to handle the "unexpected alert open"?

Tags: java, selenium

I got an issue with Selenium throwing `timeout exception` because of a pop up window

```
  unexpected alert open
  not provide any stacktrace information)
  Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds
```

The alert has `OK` and `CANCEL` buttons. I know two ways to handle this

---

The first way is reopen a new session

```
driver.quit();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

---

Second way is using Robot class

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

However, this methods are not time efficient. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I got this: "NoSuchAlertError: no alert open"... It's not consistent, sometimes the tests pass, sometimes it gives me that error when i try to accept the alert... any idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: If something is not consistently failing in WebDriver, it is 95% chance that it is a timing issue.  You can use `new WebDriverWait(driver).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())` to wait for it.

Comment: I'm using Nodejs Selenium, can you provide a more detailed example? Many thanks

Comment: nevermind, i just sleep(1000) before i accept it, thanks anyway :D

Comment: Nodejs code: driver.wait(webdriver.until.alertIsPresent()).then(()=> {
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        });

Comment: I am using Selenium 3.4.2 and the command changed to browser.switch_to.alert.accept()

Comment: Hi Do you have recommendation on how to implement this for Cordova Multi-webview based app? automated using Appium-Java. Thanks

Comment: Ok but from where `driver` comes from ? Nobody explain that, and we have a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchTo' of undefined` ...

Answer (score 22):

### Methods to handle alerts in Selenium

1. **Decide on each individually**

If you need to take action on each alert in your tests individually, the driver gives you the option to switch to the alert and decide to either accept or dismiss it.

```java
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

---

2. **Handle by default setup**

When you want all the alerts handled in the same way, you can set a global [capability](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) at the start of the test execution to **ACCEPT**, **INGORE** or **DISMISS** alerts by **default** when they appear.

```java
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
```

---

3. **Using Robot class**

Alternatively, you could use Robot class to send an Enter key event, which would accept the alert.

```java
Robot r = new Robot();
 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

---

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {

    boolean presentFlag = false;

    try {

        // Check the presence of alert
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        // Alert present; set the flag
        presentFlag = true;
        // if present consume the alert
        alert.accept();
        //( Now, click on ok or cancel button )

    } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
        // Alert not present
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return presentFlag;
}
```

I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: it's an unexpected alert it can appear any where. so do you think after every line of code I call this Boolean function `isAlertPresent()`, if your answer is NO, then please edit and explain how to call this function optimally,without repeating/calling every-time.

Comment: @paul, you should change according to your need. i have written overall not for specific part.

Comment: if sure about the popup then only use try catch code no need to check the popup is open or not just use driver.switchTo().alert();. but some time situation is just like popup will open or not i.e. no sure about the popup is open every time. i have such a situation in my application so i have handled as above. In my situation, while i have selected specific value from drop down then popup is open. this not for all the values of drop down. if you have any better technique always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

More often this issue is bothersome in that it appears at unpredictable places in the system under test. Right now, I dont think there exists ways to handle ALL of these uncretainities automatically by configuration in the webdriver. My general advice would be to wrap the webDriver in a Proxy and use some kind of a dynamic proxy to wrap all the webdriver methods. This way you get a single point of control over unpredictable alerts, get to do logging or evaluate method performance, handle random unreachableBrowser Exceptions, handle random StaleElementException etc. I find this to be very useful for a variety of situations, at a small performance penalty.

```
        Class WebDriverProxy implements InvocationHandler{
       WebDriverWrapperImpl impl = new WebDriverWrapperImpl();

        public String clickByXPath(String xpath)  {
            return (String)handleInvocation(impl,"clickByXPath", new Object[]{xpath});
            //  return impl.clickByXPath( xpath) ;
        }


    /**All fail fast strategies could be centralized here., no need of any assertion errors in libraries,
         * However it makes sense to wrap webdriver exceptions as either recoverable or nonrecoverable
         * recoverable ones are like unexpected hangs on the browser, which could be handled at the test runner level, wherein the 
         * whole test can be retried.
         * irrecoverable ones are also mostly handled at the test runner level, but capable of being caught at the test script level *  
         **/
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
        {
            Object o = null;
            Throwable target = null;
            try{
                o = method.invoke(proxy, args);
            }       
            catch(InvocationTargetException ee){            
                target = ee.getTargetException();
                throw target;
            }
            return o;
        }

        public Object handleInvocation(Object proxy, String method, Object[] args){     

            Object toReturn = null;
            Method m = null;
            Class[] classes = new Class[args.length];
            for(int i = 0;i<args.length;i++){
                classes[i]=String.class;
            }
            for(Object x:args){
            logBuffer.append(x.toString()+","); 
            }
            log.trace("WebDriverProxy. "+method+"("+logBuffer.toString()+")");
            logBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            try{
                 m = proxy.getClass().getMethod(method,classes);

                toReturn = invoke(proxy,m, args);

            }catch(NoSuchMethodException e){    
                e.printStackTrace();

            }catch( StaleElementReferenceException e){
                log.debug("Exception was of tye "+e.getClass().getCanonicalName());






            }
            catch(UnreachableBrowserException | NoSuchElementException e){
                log.debug("Exception was of tye "+e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                //If the NoSuchelement is due to suspect Alerts being present, switchToAlert() and alert.accept() here.
            }



            return toReturn;
        }



        }


class WebDriverWrapperImpl {
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  public String clickByXPath(String xpath)  throws Exception{
            driver.findElement(By.Xpath(xpath)).click();
            return driver.getTitle();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(ACCEPT);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Instead of `ACCEPT` you can pass the
following enum constants `ACCEPT`, `ACCEPT_AND_NOTIFY`, `DISMISS`, `DISMISS_AND_NOTIFY`, `IGNORE`
according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Configure `DesiredCapabilities` to accept unexpected alter behavior.

```java
final DesiredCapabilities chromeCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
chromeCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
/*
 * Other options...
 */
chromeCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
ChromDrvier driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeCapabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by Java too. Create Java class and implement InvocationHandler interface. Override invoke method, in this method have your logic to handle alert/pop up or any event which you want to handle. Then wrap this class instance with you Webelement so whenever it performing any action on each webelement it will call this wrapper method.

Hope this helps - here is the link on implementation https://www.vinsguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-handle-annoying-random-popup-alerts/

Answer (score 0):

If your are using any frameworks like TestNG , you can use Listeners like ITestListener e.t.c where you have to override some of the methods like BeforeCommand and afterCommand. So in BeforeCommand, implement code for alert to dismiss and check the beauty. When ever selenium command is getting executed, this beforeCommand method will call automatically and check whether alert is present or not . If yes it will dismiss and execute your command . I hope it will solve u r problem

Comment: I haven't found something like beforeCommand in TestNG listeners but found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35692021/3562925) answer that by implementing `WebDriverEventListener` is possible what you suggested.