# Random popup survey

Tags: java, selenium, random, popup, webdriver

I have a website that generates a random survey popup.
I have to refresh the browser about 20 to 50 times to get that pop up.
But Selenium does not report it if it sees it anyways. What's the best way to write this code using selenium webdriver and java. I've tried switchTo.frame(frameid) or window. I've tried getting window handles. Nothing seems to work. I need to verify that the popup appears for certain urls in the site.

Comment: might be duplicate of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173195/how-to-handle-the-unexpected-alert-open/19173750?noredirect=1#comment39092068_19173750

Comment: switchto alert does not work either.

Comment: do you have any html or a link to the page in question?

Comment: If it's that invite popup then it's just a div that pops up on the page.  I'm not sure what triggers it but there is a delay in it showing up.  Perhaps a wait would allow this or a mouse move function would trigger it...only showed up the first time I hit the page.  You need to track down what is actually triggering that event...