# unexpected alert open after selecting an option protractor js

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

When i try to handle alert by using [How to handle the "unexpected alert open"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173195/how-to-handle-the-unexpected-alert-open), it is not working. Actually it is working in other place but it is not working after selecting delete option

Test case:

```
  dropdown_helper = require('./select_dropdown.js'); 
  var delete_status = element(by.model('courses.single.status'));
  delete_status.sendKeys(dropdown_helper.selectDropdownByNumber('3'));
  ptor.sleep(1000);

  // <- clicking yes to delete
  ptor.driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

select_dropdown.js

```
exports.selectDropdownByNumber = function (index) {
 element.all(by.css('select option'))
  .then(function (options) {
      options[index].click();
  });
};
```

Can anyone help me?